# Sending different objects via ajax with .blur()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to perform a `.blur()` that changes parameters depending on which tag loses focus. However, I want to be able to send different objects in the ajax request depending on which `id` loses focused. Being new to jquery and javascript, I'm not sure how to do this. I could build 2 functions that are identical but send different objects but I prefer to build one.

code:

```
   function ajaxRequest(event, endpoint, payload, request) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: endpoint,
            type: request,
            data: payload,
            success: function() {
                console.log("test")
            }
        });
    }

    //pseudo code
    $("#signup-email, #signup-username").blur(function(event) {
        if (id == "signup-email") {
           var payload = {"test1": 1};
        } else if (id == "signup-username") {
           var payload = {"test2": 0}
        }
        ajaxRequest(event, "auth/check_availability/", payload,"GET");
    });
```

HTML:

```
<tr><th></th><td><input id="signup-username" maxlength="50" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th></th><td><input id="signup-email" maxlength="50" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set `id`. Use `this.id` to get the ID of the element they clicked on.

```
$("#signup-email, #signup-username").blur(function(event) {
    if (this.id = "signup-email") {
       var payload = {"test1": 1};
    } else if (this.id = "signup-username") {
       payload = {"test2": 0}
    }
    ajaxRequest(event, "auth/check_availability/", payload,"GET");
});
```